# Canada visitor visa: what proves that you are entering just temporarily?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, tourist-visas

I am trying to get a visitor/tourist visa for Canada. What can be shown as a proof that I will not stay permanently Canada? The website says I can show hotel bookings or flight tickets. As I don't have the visa yet, I haven't done either of them.

I hold an Indian passport. I have been living in the United States for the past 2 years on a student visa. I have an employment permit (EAD card) and am currently working as a software engineer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally what you need at least if *proof of onward travel*. This means a reservation or ticket out of the country for a date that falls within your allowed stay.

The most common is a *return airfare* but can be any ticket in your name out of Canada, so even if you some from the US, you can have a ticket to fly to Iceland or India for that matter (anywhere outside of Canada). You are not limited to flights though which should be easy considering Canada and the US share the longest land border in the world (8893km). There are numerous trains and buses you can book in advance from Canada to the US.

Depending on your confidence in getting the visa, you can buy a normal airfare back but you can also opt for a fully refundable fare. There is always the chance of not getting the visa but this is how many countries work, even ones where getting a visa is not so easy. You may also want to get a  refundable lodging, just in case.

When *proof of onward travel* is not enough, evidence that you hold a job can help. This will come as a letter from your employer saying that your are employed permanently or at least for a long contract. It may also state the day you intend to resume work after your holiday.

Comment: Travelers crossing the land border by car (or presumably on foot, though I doubt there are many people applying for visas to walk into Canada) are not generally asked to show proof of onward travel.

Comment: They are not, but if you apply for a visa, you are asked to specify it. So it is needed even if you never actually have to show it. Same story happened to me for Brazil, I needed confirmed flights and  hotel bookings but no one ever saw them besides the Brazil embassy in Quito.

Comment: Thaks for the answer, As i mentioned I am working as a software engineer and I do have a letter from the employer stating the same. Do I still need air tickets ?

Comment: Yes, the most important thing you need is proof of onward travel, even if they are refundable. Most cases, that is the only thing they ask for. The employment letter is additional.

Comment: OK, Probably I can book a refundable ticket. And cancel it because I do not have any specific travel plans. Do they check the status of the ticket too ?